# How to remove an entire git branch and history

Tags: git

I have a git repo with many commits and branches.  A while ago, two main branches diverged and will never be merged together.  I'd like to make a copy of the repo and completely delete one of the main branches, deleting all of the commits and branch history.  I know how to make the copy, but I can't figure out how to do the delete.  For example, say my current repo looks like the following, where 00, 01, 02, 12, etc are commits, and B1, B2, etc are branches.

```
                         B6
                   /24---25
                  /
     B1        B2/       B3 
00---01---02---03---04---05
       \
        \
         \12---13---14---15
          B4             B5
```

After deleting, I want my repo to look like the following:

```
     B1   
00---01---12---13---14---15
          B4             B5
```

I could probably manually delete each unwanted branch and do a git gc, but that would be very labor intensive (a couple hundred branches, at least) and error prone.

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks very much.

Comment: *I could probably manually delete each unwanted branch and do a git gc*. Or you could write a script in your shell scripting language of choice to do it.

Comment: Use `git for-each-ref refs/heads` (probably with `--format` as well) to get a list of all branch names. Then, delete from the list the names you want to *keep*. Use a command loop to run `git branch -D` on each remaining name. You're now ready to run the `git gc`.

Comment: Just to add a pinch to torek's proposed solution, you can use this simple format for your list `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads` Also, don't forget to checkout `B5` (or any staying branch) *before* your bulk delete, or the process might halt if it happens to reach a candidate for deletion that is currently checked out.